# Knockout.JS How to bind dom element bind

Tags: knockout.js

I want to draw my category tree that generated in JS using knockout binding,
but I can not binding with DOM Element.

```
<div id="category_list" data-bind="html:categoryTree">
    List Area   
</div>
```

//JS

```
function appendSubCategories(categories) {
    var container = document.createElement("ul");
    $.each(categories, function (i, category) {
        var currentNode = document.createElement("li");
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: 2px");
        span.className = "folder";
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(category.Name));
        currentNode.appendChild(span);

        if (category.Subfolders.length > 0) {
            currentNode.appendChild(appendSubCategories(category.Subfolders));
        }
        container.appendChild(currentNode);
    });
    return container;
}

function CategoryViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.categoryTree =ko.observable(); 

    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Admin/Category/getCategoryList", function (categoryList) {
            self.categoryTree(appendSubCategories(categoryList));

            //self.categoryTree("<p>This is working</p>);
            //$("#category_list").html(categoryTree);

            $(".folder").click(function () {
                console.log(this);
            });
        });


    });
}// End CategoryViewModel
ko.applyBindings(new CategoryViewModel());
```

If run above code, it print,

**[object HTMLUListElement]**

How should I do to make bind with Element data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could simply update the observable like this:

```
var html = $(appendSubCategories(categoryList)).html();
self.categoryTree(html);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but why would you want to put all those elements in the DOM and than only use the html-text? Use those elements directly (like Grim showed) or just create a html-string (see my anwser)

Comment: Actually, I somewhat agree. I upvoted Grim's answer. That said, if you look at OP's code, he never actually inserts the elements into the DOM. So AFAIK there is no real performance penalty here.

Answer (score 4):

The html binding expect the html content as text. To have the binding accept DOM elements i think you need a custom binding - for example (using jquery here for dom manipulation):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.element = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var elem = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).empty();
    $(element).append(elem);
}
```

and then use it like:

```
<div data-bind="element: categoryTree"></div>
```

For more info on custom bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace appendSubCategories with this:

```
function appendSubCategories(categories) {
    var container = "<ul>";
    $.each(categories, function (i, category) {
        container += '<li><span class="folder" style="margin-left: 2px;">' + category.Name + '</span>';
        if (category.Subfolders.length > 0) {
            container += appendSubCategories(category.Subfolders);
        }
        container += '</li>';
    });
    return container + "</ul>";
}
```