# How to sync Knockout.JS with data already rendered in DOM by server?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, knockout.js

In the examples I have seen so far, Knockout seems to populate its models using contrived hardcoded data, or data which has been retrieved from some JSON request. This isn't what I want.

When my page is initially rendered, the server loops through the collection of my objects and displays them (using the server side blade syntax). That is the data that I want the model to be synced with, whereby further items could be added or removed. The question restated is how do you sync the model and view if you already have loaded and displayed items from the server?

To see an example of where hardcoded data is used, check out [their example page](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/). So instead of getting the data from the hardcoded values, how do you get it from what is already displayed?

I thought that having the `data-bind="foreach: person"` would automatically bind the server generated view and knockout model, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Currently I'm getting the following error on page load which I know has something to do with the viewmodel not being in sync.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return company }"
Message: company is not defined`

I imagine that the error is because there is no actual data bound when performing `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`. Of course, since this error is thrown, the add and remove buttons don't do anything.

**Here is the HTML/Blade:**

```
<?php
    $personsObserved = $po->personsObserved;
?>

@foreach ($personsObserved as $p)  
    <div class="personWell" data-bind='foreach: people'> 
       {{ Form::label('personsObserved[][name]', 'Name', ['class' => 'content-label']) }}
       {{ Form::text('personsObserved[][name]', $p->name, ['placeholder'=>'Person Name', 'required', 'data-bind'=>'value: name']) }}

       {{ Form::label('personsObserved[][company]', 'Company', ['class' => 'content-label']) }}
       {{ Form::text('personsObserved[][company]', $p->company, ['placeholder'=>'Company Name', 'required', 'data-bind'=>'value: company']) }}

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-bind='click: $root.removePerson'>Delete</button>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Even when I put the foreach outside of the loop, it still doesn't work.

**JavaScript**

```
var ObservedPersonModel = function(people) {

    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray(people);

    self.addPerson = function() {
        self.people.push({
            name: "",
            company: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePerson = function(people) {
        self.people.remove(person);
    };
};

var viewModel = new ObservedPersonModel([
    // Hardcoded values removed
    // Here is where I would guess that we get the existing property values from the DOM somehow
    /*{ name: "Tall Hat", company: "PeachCo"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", company: "BeachCo"}*/
]);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Resources**
I have done some other searches and here are some that were of assistance:

- [knockout.js - Get ViewModel from DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015497/knockout-js-get-viewmodel-from-dom-element)
- [Knockout.JS How to bind dom element bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761905/knockout-js-how-to-bind-dom-element-bind)

Comment: At what point do you get this error? Do you want to add your sample code so we could see more clearly what's going on?

Comment: @dotnetom the question has been updated :)   the error already appears on page load.

Comment: You're complicating things by mixing server side and client side code. I would highly suggest you only use php code to send data structures to the client. You should pass your initial collection to `viewModel.people`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the 'foreach' binding in your template, but I don't think that's the problem.

What you should do instead of placing the foreach in blade syntax, is to make a plain div with the template, but in KO's syntax (using databinds).
Then, in the JS part, you should instantiate your ObservedPersonModel (which should be Persons in plural, or PersonCollection) and bind it to the DOM to let Knockout render the items, instead of blade.

Remember that knockout renders the DOM based on the JS data, and there's no backward step.

Comment: Apologies. That was an edit error. The `foreach` is actually in there and has been edited back in. So I suppose what you're saying is that I need to figure out a way to get the Person data on the server side to be made available to that JS file. Can the JS access passed objects that came with the page?

Comment: Is it posible to make a new REST service where you can ask the list of persons? so then you'd leave the html without the blade processing, and a service that returns the whole list of persons, and that's what you'd use to initialize the PersonCollection (or make a method to fetch itself from the server)...

That's my strongest suggestion, but if you have access to add code into the html/js, you should use php to create a javascript variable, and dump there the raw object, and use that variable to initialize the PersonCollection

Comment: I now understand how Knockout works. It is driven by data, so the data must be provided to Knockout so that it can generate the HTML. What I ended up doing was creating a javascript variable with the object array encoded as JSON. Worked like a charm.